# Who first modelled water as a tetrahedron?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, history, molecules, quantum-chemistry

Who first modelled water as a tetrahedron? In this model the oxygen is at the center and the two hydrogens are at the vertices (I think, or maybe somewhere along the edges?).

[image]
[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water#/media/File:Tetrahedral_Structure_of_Water.png)

This gives the number of microstates equal to 6 and provides some insight into how and why it mixes with other substances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water#/media/File:Tetrahedral_Structure_of_Water.png

Comment: It would be useful (even essential IMO) to include this picture to clarify your question, and indicate that the tetrahedral structure is obtained by including lone electron pairs rather than only the constituent atoms (as is usually done).

Comment: Isn't this more of a question about the history of science than about physics *per se*?  Maybe it could be asked on [hsm.se] instead?

Comment: @Struggling_Student The shape of molecules like water (and lots of others) was first accurately described by [VSEPR theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) developed in 1956. That would have been the first time that water would have been modelled as a tetrahedron with the two H atoms and the two lone pairs at the corners of the tetrahedron.

Comment: @JohnRennie interesting.  Water is given as having “bent shape” (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_molecular_geometry) rather than tetrahedral.  Does the nomenclature of shapes go by atoms *only* or by atoms + lone pairs?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I don't think we would call a water molecule "tetrahedral". The point is that it's shape can only be understood by considering the tetrahedral arrangement of the hydrogen atoms **and** the lone pairs.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that (for example) any question about the conservation of energy should be moved to [HSM.SE].  But I would suggest that any question about who first came up with the idea of conservation of energy *should* be moved there.

Answer (score 2):

The first mention that I know of was by Gilbert Newton Lewis in the book [VALENCE and The Structure of Atoms and Molecules](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b3219599&view=1up&seq=17&skin=2021):

> … at first sight the formula for water … appears symmetrical, although we really regard the two hydrogens as not symmetrically placed with respect to oxygen, but rather at two corners of a more or less distorted tetrahedron. This conclusion has also been drawn from the properties of liquid crystals by Vorländer (1922).

[image]
[image]